# arp -a not reporting all devices on network on MacOS

Tags: networking, ping, arp

I come across this issue consistently, and have for quite some time with different computers and OS versions.  I first run a broadcast ping over the IP range, eg, 192.168.0.255.  However `arp -a` still does not report devices which are verified as being on the network.  Sometimes it will, sometimes not.  It seems random which devices will be reported, and it is rare that I find all devices listed.

Any input on this?

Comment: Are the devices all awake? Are they expected to wake for a broadcast ping?

Comment: I don't know the definition of "awake".  They can be devices which I am currently transferring data to/from.

Answer (score 1):

ARP requests only travel on local segments, ie if some devices are on other VLANs they will not be added to a device's ARP table on a different VLAN. What is your network configuration and hardware?

Answer (score 1):

An IP stack only needs an ARP mapping when *sending* a *unicast* packet to a same-subnet host. Also, it's not safe to populate an ARP table based on the source IP and MAC addresses of received packets; a host should only update its ARP table based on sending ARP requests and getting back ARP responses.

So you need to do something like use nmap to scan the whole subnet.

Comment: nmap seems to be on the right track, however it doesn't seem to be a silver bullet (at least not for Mac.)  Trying a "broadcast" as root, nmap -Pn 192.168.0-255.1-254 just seems to hang forever.  I even tried  nmap -Pn 192.168.0-255.1-2, it gave the result for 192.168.0.1, then just hanged.  I tried looping using a perl script, and that worked better, but finally it hanged on 192.168.0.16.

Comment: Why do you have to run nmap as root to get MAC addresses?

Comment: I got the 192.168.0-255.1-254 formatting from the docs.  Hope that is correct.

Comment: Actually I think I might see the problem - running nmap seems to be bringing down my network :/